# Multiple login implementation

Tags: php, mysql, cloud

I'm in the phase of designing a database which will have following entities among others:

-Organization, 
-Organization_branch,
-Organization_staff

The concept is to allow ****MULTIPLE** organizations** to store their branch and staff details in **SINGLE DATABASE**.

However, I need some guideline as to how shall i implement the tables to allow each organization to **login uniquely** and perform various operations on their records only. As well as to allow each organization **staff** to login and perform various operations.

===================================

## Organization table to store data of various organizations

Organization_Id,
Name,
Short_name,
Email,
Password,

===================================

## Organization_branch table to store data of various branches of each organization

Branch_id,
Organization_Id,
Location,
Cellphone,
Email,
Password,

===================================

## Organization_staff table to store data of various staff of each organization

Staff_id,
First_name,
Last_name,
Cellphone,
Designation,
Email,
Password,
Branch_id,
Organization_Id,

Comment: How about some sort of ranking system? You check what *rank* a person has and what organisation code they have, and go from there? In any case, you should provide a [mcve] when asking on SO, we are **not** a *free* coding service.

Comment: Updated my question above with sample database tables. Moreover, I just need to know if it is possible to keep a single database for multiple organizations data while allowing each organization as well as its staff unique login and access to their particular set of data?

Comment: Yes, you will have to work with some unique organisation key, so you can check what organisation that person is in. Just one column in your structure, same for the admin rights, make a ranking system where the admin need rank 10 or so